# LatestOnly filter not working when querying ADF pipeline runs

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using the Azure Data Factory queryPipelineRuns endpoint to query our pipeline run history looking to see if certain pipelines have failed in a recent time period.  I do not want to include pipelines that failed and were re-run successfully.  It seems like using the LatestOnly filter operand would give me what I want but there is no real documentation on this filter and I cannot get it to work.  The call succeeds but no filter is ever applied.

For example, I call with this body

```
"body": "{
"lastUpdatedAfter":"2024-01-07T21:00:00.0000000Z",
"lastUpdatedBefore":"2024-01-09T16:59:39.7436021Z",
"filters":[
    {"operand":"LatestOnly","operator":"Equals","values":["true"]},
    {"operand":"Status","operator":"Equals","values":["Failed"]},
    {"operand":"PipelineName","operator":"In","values":["Pipeline1","Pipeline2"]}]}
```

I've tried 'True', 'true', 'yes', and many other filter values to no effect

I still get return values like this:

```
"value": [
{
    "id": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/xxxx/RESOURCEGROUPS/xxx/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DATAFACTORY/FACTORIES/xxx/pipelineruns/xxxx",
            "runId": "xxxx",
            "debugRunId": null,
            "runGroupId": "xxxx",
            "pipelineName": "Pipeline1",
            "parameters": {},
            "invokedBy": {
                "id": "xxxx",
                "name": "Pipeline1_Trigger",
                "invokedByType": "ScheduleTrigger"
            },
            "runStart": "2024-01-08T10:30:01.3127201Z",
            "runEnd": "2024-01-08T12:39:36.5102571Z",
            "durationInMs": 7775197,
            "status": "Failed",
            "message": "Operation on target Fail1 failed: Force Fail",
            "pipelineReturnValue": {},
            "lastUpdated": "2024-01-08T12:39:36.5108261Z",
            "annotations": [],
            "runDimension": {},
            "isLatest": false
        }
```

You can see the isLatest value is false because that pipeline was re-run to a successful completion.  I want this query no not include this result.

What do I need to put in this filter value to only get the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above scenario and these are my observations.

First I took the above JSON with `LatestOnly` filter in the REST API body and got the below result.

[image]

It gave the same result as yours where it gave the `false` results as well. As the field name is `isLatest`, I tried the filter with `isLatest`, but it gave `400` error with a message like below.

```
isLatest' is not a valid filter operand. Allowed values are 'PipelineName, Status, RunStart, RunEnd, SandboxId, RunGroupId, LatestOnly, TriggeredByName'.
```

Then, I have removed the `LatestOnly` filter from the body and this is result that it gave me.

**Body:**

```
{
    lastUpdatedAfter: "2024-01-07T21:00:00.0000000Z",
    lastUpdatedBefore: "2024-01-11T21:00:00.0000000Z",
        "filters":[
    {"operand":"Status","operator":"In","values":["Failed"]},
    {"operand":"PipelineName","operator":"In","values":["pipeline4","mypipeline"]}
]
}
```

[image]

You can see it gave the same results with `LatestOnly` filter and without that as well. **This might be a bug** in the ADF. The only workaround for it will be getting all failed pipeline runs JSON (including `isLatest` values `true` and `false`) and filter out the **false runs** by the field `isLatest` using any programming language logic.

Comment: You have repeated the same tests that I have.

Comment: Yes for confirmation I have rechecked it. I have raised a bug request in Github https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/issues/639. You can follow this.

Comment: That repository is just opensource code samples for ADF.  I'm doubtful that MS is going to see your report but thank you

Comment: @huisek, Can you try `{"operand":"LatestOnly","operator":"Equals","values":[true]}` as mentioned in this issue https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/issues/639.